# How to create spend key and view key from public address

Tags: mymonero

i have to create Monero wallet on https://moneroaddress.org/. And did not note spend key and view key. just note public address.
Is it possible to create spend key and view key from public address?

Answer (score 4):

No. You can obtain them from the seed mnemonic (25 words) if you saved those. If it was possible from the address, then anyone could steal anyone's money.

If you already created the wallet from the keys/seed, you can get them from the wallet. If you just made the address, and closed the window without saving the mnemonic words or keys - that wallet is gone forever.

Comment: my wallet gone with 1.2 etheruem